# How can I smooth rotation which is based on cursor position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private float rotationZ;

        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize();
    


    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ);
```

So far my code will get the cursor position and instantly perform a transform. However, if I move the cursor near the center of the pivot, the rotation will be instantaneous and choppy. How can I add a slight smooth to this, to make it travel from point A to point B slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would store the actual target value in a field and then move towards it

```
private Quaternion targetRotation;
private Camera camera;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Camera.main is quite expensive so rather store the reference
    camera = Camera.main;
  
    // Initially set your current rotation as target
    // especially important if you don't always update the target rotation but e.g.
    // only if a certain button is pressed  
    targetRotation = transform.rotation;
}

private void Update ()
{
    UpdateTargetRotation();
    RotateTowardsTarget();
}

private void UpdateTargetRotation ()
{
    var difference = (camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position).normalized;
    var targetRotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetRotationZ);
}
```

Now for the `RotateTowardsTarget` you have many options.

One of them would indeed be using [`Quaternion.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) with a certain interpolation factor. Here you interpolate smoothly towards the target value but very fast at the beginning and get slower and slower the closer you get to the target value regardless of how much you rotate in total. This also might never really reach the exact target value.

```
// Adjust in the Inspector
public float interpolationFactor = 5f;

private void RotateTowardsTarget ()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, interpolationFactor * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Or another option would be to rather use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) which rotates with a fixed speed

```
// Adjust in the Inspector
public float anglePerSecond = 45;

private void RotateTowardsTarget ()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Mathf.Lerp`

Example of how you could use it:

```
    float rotationZ;

    //Changes how quickly will rotate 
    const float rotationSpeed = 0.58f;

    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize();

    rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    float lerpRotation = Mathf.Lerp(transform.rotation.z, rotationZ, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, lerpRotation);
```

Comment: Yeah, lerp is what I'm looking for definetly, but I don't think your example works because lerpRotation never actually reaches 1. It just multiplies rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime which continuously returns the same (or nearly the same) value. I've been trying to fix it but can't find anything.

Comment: @Greenbean77 in this case it doesn't matter since you always take a new start rotation and then interpolate again. This just gets slower and slower the closer you get to the target value

Comment: However using the `rotation.z` is **wrong**! A `Quaternion` has **four** components x,y,z,w and they move in the range `-1` to `1` so that is not what you want to access ever ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should use Quaternion.Slerp() in a coroutine.
You check the cursor position every FixedUpdate then start a coroutine that interpolates and sets the rotation every frame until the next FixedUpdate comes. The created lag is basicly unnoticable and it looks silky smooth.

For the interpolation t value you should use a variable that stores the time elapsed since the last FixedUpdate (you add that up from time.deltatimes), and to get the t you just divide it by 0.02secs.

Then when the coroutin finishes, set the rotation to the final value.